# Azure powershell Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Tags: powershell, azure-runbook

I had a working azure powershell app that was working and today the powershell app stopped working with the following error:

```
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryContract.set_PropertyNameResolver(System.Func`2<System.String,System.String>)'.
```

I am very confused as I am not using Newtonsoft in the application code. Here is my application code:

```
   Param
(

    [Parameter (Mandatory= $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)

if ($WebhookData){

$requestBody = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody) 
$priority = $requestBody.priority
$IPList = $requestBody.IPList
$rule = $requestBody.rule
$UserName = $requestBody.Name
$subNet = $requestBody.Subnet

if (!$subNet) { $subNet = '32'}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'

function Login() {
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        Write-Verbose "Logging in to Azure..." -Verbose

        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
}



Login



$RGName = 'resourcegroup'
function Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule
{
$ApiVersions = Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceTypes |
Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq 'sites' |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ApiVersions

$LatestApiVersion = $ApiVersions[0]

$WebAppConfig = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' -ResourceName $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion

$WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions + @($rule) | 
Group-Object name | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Last 1 }

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $WebAppConfig.ResourceId -Properties $WebAppConfig.Properties -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion -Force 
}


$webAppNames = 'webapp-test'
$webAppList = $webAppNames.split(',')
Foreach($webAppName in $webAppList) { 
$IPList= @($IPList-split ",")
Write-Host "IPList found "$IPList"."
$increment = 1
foreach ($element in $IPList)
{
if ($element -eq "" -OR $element -eq " ") {continue}
else
{
$element=$element.Trim()
$rule = [PSCustomObject]@{
ipAddress = "$($element)/$subNet"
action = "Allow"
priority = "$priority"
name = $UserName+ $increment}
$increment++
Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -AppServiceName "$WebAppName" -rule $rule
}
}
}
}
```

I am using Azure runbook to run this powershell and sending in my data through a post request

Comment: The error is coming from the azure cmdlets, it seems this json implementation is problematic, and it's a known issue when using multiple azure modules: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4380 - The Azure SDK team is moving away from it per the link below, so maybe check if your module version has updated recently, or try updating it manually if it hasn't? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/previewing-azure-sdks-following-new-azure-sdk-api-standards/

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thank you so much for this, I have been breaking my head with this

Answer (score 1):

The commands you are using belong to the deprecated `AzureRM` module, try to migrate to the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.8.0) module.

Navigate to the automation account in the portal -> `Modules gallery` -> import the `Az.Accounts`, `Az.Resources` modules, then use the script below.

```
   Param
(

    [Parameter (Mandatory= $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)

if ($WebhookData){

$requestBody = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody) 
$priority = $requestBody.priority
$IPList = $requestBody.IPList
$rule = $requestBody.rule
$UserName = $requestBody.Name
$subNet = $requestBody.Subnet

if (!$subNet) { $subNet = '32'}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'

function Login() {
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        Write-Verbose "Logging in to Azure..." -Verbose

        Connect-AzAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
}



Login



$RGName = 'resourcegroup'
function Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule
{
$ApiVersions = Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceTypes |
Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq 'sites' |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ApiVersions

$LatestApiVersion = $ApiVersions[0]

$WebAppConfig = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' -ResourceName $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion

$WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions + @($rule) | 
Group-Object name | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Last 1 }

Set-AzResource -ResourceId $WebAppConfig.ResourceId -Properties $WebAppConfig.Properties -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion -Force 
}


$webAppNames = 'webapp-test'
$webAppList = $webAppNames.split(',')
Foreach($webAppName in $webAppList) { 
$IPList= @($IPList-split ",")
Write-Host "IPList found "$IPList"."
$increment = 1
foreach ($element in $IPList)
{
if ($element -eq "" -OR $element -eq " ") {continue}
else
{
$element=$element.Trim()
$rule = [PSCustomObject]@{
ipAddress = "$($element)/$subNet"
action = "Allow"
priority = "$priority"
name = $UserName+ $increment}
$increment++
Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -AppServiceName "$WebAppName" -rule $rule
}
}
}
}
```